# how to make a video playlist with embed from other website video uploads. Ex aparat.com

Tags: wordpress, video, embed, playlist

I have a website for learning.
I want to add a video playlist from my country video site named aparat.com
you can learn how to make a video playlist with embed code from aparat?
my website uses WordPress.
I see another site a playlist from aparat embed. but I don't know how to make

Comment: Hey and welcome. Can you share what you have tried? Do you want do do it in PHP (like wordpress is written)?

Comment: Please provide some code!

Answer (score 1):

Any aparat film have a special link that not change.
[https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/{{hash}}/vt/frame](https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/%7B%7Bhash%7D%7D/vt/frame)

{{hash}} is latest section of your video page in aparat.com
for example
https://www.aparat.com/v/6EBX3

> > 6EBX3

So your video link will be:
https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/6EBX3/vt/frame

It's your special video link

Now you must create a slider (with any plugin that supports video links) and add your video links.